# What is the <userPermission> for RunFlows to add it to an MDAPI deploy

Tags: metadata-api, permissions, mdapideploy

I've extracted the metadata for the profiles, but cannot find any setting that allows me to deploy this. I tried using this, but it tells me 'RunFlows' it not a valid option. How can I deploy this setting (since we have multiple orgs and I don't want to have to log in to each one and edit the setting for 4 profiles in each).

```
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>RunFlows</name>
</userPermissions>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API name for that permission is RunFlow rather than RunFlows.

Although not official, this page from Daniel Ballinger is super useful for the API Names for all the user permissions on Permission Sets and Profiles: [Mapping between Salesforce Permission Name and the Label](http://www.fishofprey.com/2020/10/mappings-between-salesforce-permission.html)

Comment: That's really handy - I've bookmarked it for future reference.